# ied installer with phantomjs/phantomjs-prebuilt

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs

Ied installer which installs parallel sub-dependencies has an issue with phantomjs/pahtnomjs-prebuilt.

Problem is that custom npm installer install's package with phantomjs (downloads from github if it  does not exist in pc/virtual machine) and sets the path of it in location.js in lib folder which also not exists due to ied installer.

You can view it on lib/phantomjs.js file
on line 18

```
try {
  var location = require('./location')
  exports.path = path.resolve(__dirname, location.location)
  exports.platform = location.platform
  exports.arch = location.arch
} catch(e) {
  // Must be running inside install script.
  exports.path = null
}
```